# Removing an item in Array of objects : Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

  title = 'bucketList';
  bucketList: BucketListItem[] = [
    new BucketListItem(
      "Goa Trip",
      "Travel to Goa"
    )
  ];

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  onItemAdded(eventData) {
    this.bucketList.push(new BucketListItem(eventData.itemName, eventData.itemDescr));
  }
  onItemDeleted(delData) {   //delData = "Goa Trip"
    console.log(this.bucketList); //prints {"itemName":"Goa Trip","itemDescr":"Travel to Goa"
    this.bucketList = this.bucketList.filter(function (obj) {
      return obj.itemName !== delData;
    });
    console.log(this.bucketList);  //prints {"itemName":"Goa Trip","itemDescr":"Travel to Goa"
  }
}
```

I am trying to remove an object from the array, based on the ***itemName*** , where itemName === "Goa Trip" . But it still doesn't remove the element.

Comment: Then `delData` does not equal `"Goa Trip"`. BTW, your code snippet does not really illustrate the issue; it just throws an error when clicking "Run code snippet". Try minimizing the amount of code needed (like everything except the `filter` statement, some data for `bucketList`, and a value of `delData`).

Comment: don't you have to do `return obj.itemName !== delData.itemName`?  or maybe `return obj !== delData`. Just a guess

Comment: what is delData, can you show us the template?

Comment: @AakashGarg  It is an event emit which will be sent from another component , it has the value of "Goa Trip"

Comment: @HereticMonkey I console logged the delData , it holds the value "Goa Trip"

Comment: can you provide a stackblitz?

Comment: @AakashGarg I have changed the code snippet, please have a look

Comment: The answer is below. @Badhusha is using the method incorrectly. It creates a NEW array, it does not modify the existing one. You will need to re-assign the variable. In cases like this, the first place you should look is the documentation. It's on the first line: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter

Comment: What is puzzling is that the original code the OP had did reassign the array back to the property. I'm not sure why the OP removed that.

Comment: @HereticMonkey I have changed the code to previous form.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to assign the value after filtering.

```
bucketList = bucketList.filter(function (obj) {
      return obj.itemName !== 'Goa Trip';
});
console.log(bucketList);
```

Comment: You could make this answer better by clicking the "Copy snippet to answer" button and making the proposed change to the snippet. Then people could see the results of your change live.

Comment: Thanks. I am still new here but I'll keep that in mind.

Comment: Nothing stopping you from doing it now... :)

Comment: Hi @RahulKhunt , does the behaviour change if it is array or objects or in Object oriented approach. I did some changes, can you please have a look at my code

Comment: @Badhusha No it should have the same behavior. I've created a stackblitz. Please check here https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hqna4a?devtoolsheight=33&file=src/app/app.component.ts

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in how you set up your BucketListItem object. Here is a minimally reproducible example that does work:

```
class App {

    title = 'bucketList';
    bucketList = [
        {
            itemName: "Goa Trip",
            itemDescr: "Travel to Goa"
        }
    ];
    add(data) {
        this.bucketList.push([data.itemName, data.itemDescr]);
    }
    delete(delData) {   //delData = "Goa Trip"
        console.log(this.bucketList); //prints {"itemName":"Goa Trip","itemDescr":"Travel to Goa"
        this.bucketList = this.bucketList.filter(function (obj) {
            return obj.itemName !== delData;
        });
        console.log(this.bucketList);  //prints {"itemName":"Goa Trip","itemDescr":"Travel to Goa"
    }
}
```

Then you can run these commands:

```
const app = new App()
app.delete('Goa Trip')
```

and it behaves as expected. In your example, `"itemName"` is enclosed in double quotes, telling me that the quotes are either part of the property's literal name, or that it's JSON rather than a JavaScript object.

Try this:

```
this.bucketList = this.bucketList.filter(function (obj) {
    return obj['"itemName"'] !== delData;
});
```

If it works then you have double quotes as part of the item's literal name. Since there is no property `itemName` but rather `"itemName"` then you aren't matching anything with your filter method.

Answer (score 0):

I found the error, it was due to the **trialing** and **leading** spaces in the ***itemName***. Now I used the javascript ***trim()*** function. And it is working fine now.